# Как узнать содержит ли одна строка слова из другой?

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, c++, javascript

Всем доброго вечера (утра, дня, ночи), я сейчас реализовываю валидатор чата на матерные сообщения от пользователей, решил сильно не мудрить, ибо если кто и захочет "матюгнуться, то он что-нибудь да и придумает), но примитивную проверку все же решил сделать.

Есть строка с "плохими" словами, разделенные между собой пробелом, необходимо проверить строку от пользователя, на содержание таких слов, и, если оно будет найдено, заменить, например, звездочкой) а так-как я с регулярными выражениями на вы, то прощу помощи у сообщества ХэшКод'а)

Comment: разделите слова палкой - | 

слово|другое|третье - значит одно из этих трех слов

Comment: @eicto, представить строку регуляркой, пожалуй, самое удобное и простое решение, спасибо (:

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Доброго времени суток! Обычно для таких задач используют расстояние Левенштейна - оно часто используется для фильтрации спама и т.п. Алгоритм не очень сложный и позволяет учесть инварианты слов. Много полезного можно найти на Википедии:

[Расстояние Левенштейна](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%9B%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%88%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B0)

Если знаете английский, то более подробно (и с примерами) есть в анлийской версии:

[Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance)

Надеюсь Вам это поможет)

Comment: @progzdeveloper, вам моя огромная благодарность, этот метод наиболее близко подходит к проблеме решения подобных задач) алгоритм действительно прост, при небольших оптимизациях дает весьма высокую производительность, при этом достигается поразительная точность - непропорциональная затратам;) - детектирования искомых слов. Спасибо за наводку)

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста!

Answer (score 3):

Тестировал на python-3.2

```
import re

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # строка с матерными словами
    mature_list = 'Uшвно shat hsssss'
    # строка пользователя
    input_string = 'Мое имя Uшвно. my uncle is hsssss. oh shat!'
    # генерирование цикла для массива из строки пользователя с использованием
    # регулярного выражения (\W+) для разделения пунктуации
    for e in re.split('(\W+)', input_string):
        # проверка слова из массива с матерными словами с разделением по пробелу
        if e in mature_list.split():
            # замена матерных слов на символ '*'
            input_string = input_string.replace(e, '*') 
    print (input_string)

>>>> Мое имя *. my uncle is *. oh *!
```

Comment: спасибо за хороший пример с описанием)

Answer (score 2):

Можно преобразовать обе строки в массив, разбивая по пробелу (`.split(' ');`), после в цикле перебирать до совпадения